# Flutter - A resource failed to call release

Tags: flutter

When I run my app sometimes I receive an message in the console stating:

W/System : A resource failed to call release.

It doesn't always happen, so I'm having a hard time tracking down the problem. Is there a way to make the console specify which resource it was?

Thanks

Comment: You can look at memory profiler because you can't get alot from your logcat.

Comment: This turns out to be the same as this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386527/1864688 (not immediately obvious due to slightly different message--turns out the message is generated programmatically). I've posted an answer there about how to get more diagnostic info.

Comment: @guest That seems promising, but how could I implement that in Flutter? Your answer for that question is relevant for Java. Thanks

Comment: do you have a way to add java code to your project? the good thing is the snippet from the other answer doesn't have to be integrated with your app code. it just needs to run independently to flip that switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can track it by using [Flutter DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools). Although, in one of the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554237/w-system-a-resource-failed-to-call-release-flutter#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=This%20error%20is%20mostly%20due,the%20leak%20using%20dart%20devtools.) mentioned that the warning could be due some memory leak. It could be best that you could verify it yourself using the said Flutter DevTools.

Here are some references that you might find helpful:

- [How to find memory leaks in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674085/how-to-find-memory-leaks-in-flutter/62471179#62471179)
- [Flutter: Don’t Fear the Garbage Collector](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30)
- [Dart DevTools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nq43mP7hjAE)