# W/System: A resource failed to call release. FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter

I have a reading app ebook. After reading several chapters the device kills the app after overloading the memory. When jumping from one chapter to another, I receive the following: W/System: A resource failed to call release. I saw the same answers on other same question on stack but nothing really helpful.

The problem is so frustrating and I cannot find a solution to it. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This error is mostly due to a memory leak caused by your app or packages your app use. You can find out what's causing the leak using dart devtools.

Find out more on how to find the leaks here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62471179/10672131

Comment: I stopped getting this error once I added `FilePickerStatus.done;` after picking files using `file_picker` package.