# Firebase Auth crashes the Android emulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing mobile Flutter app with using of Firebae Auth. Recently my app started to crash when I'm trying to authenticate through Firebase. It's opens Chrome with captcha page and then emulator stop responding and message `W/System  ( 3884): A resource failed to call end.` appeared in the log console. If I didn't shut down emulator quickly, it can cause to my entire PC stop responding, so it's looks like memory leak. Firstly, I tried to reproduce same steps on web version of app in Chrome, so captcha popups opens too, but there is no problem to solve it and complete authentication. Then I tried to auth in app on real device, there were no problems and captcha screen doesn't appear at all. Lastly, I tried to reproduce same issue in emulator with the same settings on my laptop, but it works fine and captcha screen doesn't been shown.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554237/w-system-a-resource-failed-to-call-release-flutter ? Without a minimum reproducible code sample it's hard to determine the problem.