# how to identify root cause of W/System: A resource failed to call close. on Android

Tags: android

my current android application regularly reports this logcat message

```
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

having searched for how to identify the root cause i have tried the following approaches, none of which have worked...

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(
                VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                    .penaltyDeath()
                    .build()
            )
```

and this

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(
                VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectAll()
                    .penaltyDeath()
                    .build()
            )
```

and

```
try {
            Class.forName("dalvik.system.CloseGuard")
                .getMethod("setEnabled", Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType)
                .invoke(null, true)
        } catch (e: ReflectiveOperationException) {
            throw java.lang.RuntimeException(e)
        }
```

my application targets these versions of android

```
 compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

where am i going wrong?

how can i discover which resource is not calling close?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [W/System: A resource failed to call release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911580/w-system-a-resource-failed-to-call-release)

Comment: @StanislavBondar thats one of the resources i had already looked at and tried all the options listed. none of the approaches listed on your link gave any additional information

Comment: why the close vote? i have found the existing questions and answers for this issue and clearly stated these do not solve my issue. i have spent time on trying published solutions i now need additional assistance. i thought that was what so is all about?

Comment: Did you manage to find the culprit? I'm getting the same message with "close", "release" and sometimes even both but always right when the app starts (right around when "onCreate" is called).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message. I looked at what resources I had declared in the main activity and took a guess it was the ListAdapter. So I cleared() it onDestroy.
The message went away.

I'm sorry I don't have a better answer.